# How to stop a plugin to send queries on a specific wp page

Tags: mysql, wordpress, nginx, plugins

I need quite a few plugins on my page, but, most of them are needed only on once page not all.

I tried Asset Cleanup to "unload" js and css from a plugin,
and also plugin organizer

e.j on homepage i do not need "automatic-youtube-plugin" so i untick that to not load.

BUT on query monitor, i  still see  "automatic-youtube-plugin" send some queries and they slow down my page a lot

any way to force a plugin to not send any query on specific pages ?

thank you

*query monitor say 800+ queries on homepage what could be the problem

Comment: you can edit the php. js and css files manually, but of course you must learn how they work first.

Comment: How you have unstuck the plugin?

Comment: with asset cleanup you can choose which js and css to load on which page